# How do Repetier coordinates setup work

Tags: slic3r, repetier-host

I am using Repetier Host and Slic3r Prusa 1.36.2 - (the website says 1.2.9 is the latest version - however I don't believe this is the problem) .  The printer is a Anet A3

With my current setup I am printing mirrored - I can mirror the objects in Repetier before slicing , however then the preview picture is wrong, and worse I have to remember.

I have a Anet A3, the connectors for the motors are polarized and if I swap the X and Y cables when I home the X and Y motors move in the wrong direction.

I believe the problem is the coordinates and I don't fully understand the Repetier coordinates. This is how I believe it is setup (these are Slic3r screen shots ) 
[image: Current Settings]

Which I will call "Front Left" however my home position is Front Right - ie I believe it should look like this

[image: correct Slicer Setup]

However these two screen shots are from the slicer - and these settings do not get used.  In the Repetier they use a different system for setup.  I tried these settings shown  in Repetier

[image]

Then everything printed in a line along the left most edge. That is the head was moved to the very right , never moved again then the platform just moved

Can someone explain what settings I should be using for Repetier for a platform setup as I have.

If I've misunderstood the Slic3r/Repetier interface then you can point that out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly sure if you have one problem or two distinctive ones.  However a few notes:

The **latest version of Slic3r PE** can always be fetched on their [GitHub release page](https://github.com/prusa3d/Slic3r/releases).  At the time of writing that would be version 1.38.5, but I concur with you that that is unlikely to be the problem.

**Mirrored objects are a clear indication that one of the Cartesian axis is swapped** (not that it is translated).  Any of the axis can be swapped, but since the peculiarity of your printer is that the homing point is at the front RIGHT, I would guess the axis that got messed up is the X one.

I have no way to test the following, but if I got the meaning of your first two pictures, then I guess the correct settings in Repetier may probably be these:

[image]

If even that fail, **check the [handedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(mathematics)) of the coordinate system of the software generating the model** you are trying to slice.  Modelling software like Blender and others are typically right-handed, but many tools for processing those model for on-screen application (movies, videogames) are left-handed.  That means that even if the model display correctly in the native editor, it may be rendered mirrored in another software.

Comment: Thanks -  yes its reversed not translated - so I'm not looking at the correct settings . The CAD program, the load object screen (pre -slicing) and the print preview screen , post slicing all have the correct handedness.  So I'm going to have to abandon this question and ask a completly new one